# how to make picture fly into the browser window and then fade out?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to make picture fly to the browser window and then fade out. I need that one picture fly into the browser window from left side,and then fade out. and then next picture. I have five picture. I need them do this one by one, over and over. Followed is my code: It is not work fine.
Method 1: Five pictures in five  and with id as "#Slogan0", "#Slogan1", ...,etc. At the beginning, "left" is "-1000px", and the first one is "display" as "block", the others "none", so that I can change them to make them disappear."moveNext" is to change pictures.

```
var sloganidPre = "#Slogan";
var slogannum = 0;
sloganid = sloganidPre + slogannum;
window.onload = function(){ 
moveNext();
}

function moveNext(){
cf.moveTo("next");  

if($(sloganid).css("display") == "block") {

    slogannum = (slogannum+1)%5;

    $(sloganid).css("display","none");
    sloganid=sloganidPre+slogannum;
    $(sloganid).css("display","block");
    $(sloganid).animate({left:"30px"});
        $(sloganid).css("opacity","0.2");
}

setTimeout(moveNext, 1500);
}
```

Method2:
Create new element to the parent node.

```
var sloganidPre = "Slogan";
var slogannum = 0;
var sloganid = "#"+sloganidPre + slogannum;

window.onload = function(){ 

$("#sloganparent").append("<div id=\""+sloganid+"\" style=\"width:744px;height:296px;position:absolute;left:-1000px;border:1px solid #0FF;overflow:hidden;display:block;\"\"><img src=\"img/"+sloganidPre+slogannum+".png\"  /></div>");
$(sloganid).animate({left:'30px',opacity:'0.2'});

moveNext();
}

function moveNext(){

cf.moveTo("next"); 
$("#sloganparent:first-child").empty();

slogannum = (slogannum+1)%5;
sloganid= "#"+sloganidPre+slogannum;

$("#sloganparent").append("<div id=\""+sloganid+"\" style=\"width:744px;height:296px;position:absolute;left:-1000px;border:1px solid #0FF;overflow:hidden;\"><img src=\"img/"+sloganidPre+slogannum+".png\"  /></div>");

var i=0;
for (i=-1000; i<30; i++) {
    document.getElementById(new String(sloganid)).style.left= new String("\""+i+"px\"");
}
setTimeout(moveNext, 1500);                     
}
```

Jquery seems not to get the element which is created dynamically. Two methods are not work fine. Anyway I just want to know how to deploy the pictures as the titile said. Any method is fine. tks for ur consideration.

Comment: A quick google on jQuery fly-in gave me this for example http://www.spritely.net/

Comment: I need them disappear after they fly in. 0 in and then fadeout. 1 in and then fadeout. 2 in and then fadeout. 3 in and then fadeout. 4 in and then fadeout. 0 in and then fadeout. ....... @mplungjan

Comment: I have searched on google and bing. I didnt find better method for me.